# Why is chart-data not showing?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

Why is chart-data not showing?

I pass to the "data" array
But it does not show anything ... But if you make data, then everything will work

My data
[image]

Default data
[image]

My files (income)
Dashboard > DashboardView > Charts
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-glitter-c868j

```js
// Charts.js
       const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
         options: {
     chart: {
       id: "basic-bar"
     },
     xaxis: {
       categories: moment.monthsShort()
     }
     },
     series: [
      {
       name: "Доход",
       data: [incomeData] // My data - console.log(incomeData) - 4
      }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to have only one state object and don't nest different states like you are currently. Remove the `data: [incomeData]` and use a single state object to manage the chart state.

Something like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/ru";

const ChartsView = props => {
  const { income } = props;

  
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    options: {
      chart: {
        id: "basic-bar"
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: moment.monthsShort()
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Доход",
        data: []
      }
    ]
  });

  const handleData = (dataFeed) => {

    const formattedDataFeed = 'format the data ready for the chart'

    setChartOptions({
      ...chartOptions, 
      series: [{
        name: chartOptions.series[0].name,
        data: [
          {
            ...chartOptions.series[0].data
          },
          {
            ...formattedDataFeed
          }
        ]
      }]
    })
  }

  return (
    <Chart
      options={chartOptions.options}
      series={chartOptions.series}
      type="area"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
    />
  );
};

export default ChartsView;
```

You were changing the state of the `incomeData` and this was not changing any state associated with the `<Chart />`.
You need to change the state associated with the `<Chart />` so the `chartOptions`.

I hope that works and helps?